# TypeError: 'function' is not a function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The full error is `TypeError: doFollow is not a function. (In 'doFollow(index), 'doFollow is undefined)`

I'm new to React Native so I'm not quite sure what the problem may be, heres the code:

```
render(){
      const followReq = this.props.navigation.getParam('followRequest', '0')
      const doFollow = this.props.navigation.getParam('doFollow', '')
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
            followReq.map((frn, index) =>  (
                <Button 
                    key={frn}
                    title={`Follow ${frn}`}
                    onPress={() => doFollow(index)}
                />
            ))
        }
      </View> 
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete code?

Comment: You called `doFllow(index)` with out using `this` keyword. Right thing should be like `onPress={() => this.doFollow(index)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
  const followReq = this.props.navigation.getParam('followRequest', '0')
  const doFollow = this.props.navigation.getParam('doFollow', '')
 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
       { followReq.map((frn, index) =>  (
            <Button 
                key={frn}
                title={`Follow ${frn}`}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.doFollow(index);}}/>)) }
   </View>);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access your navigation params like below.

```
render(){
      const followReq = this.props.navigation.state.params.followRequest;
      const doFollow = this.props.navigation.state.params.doFollow;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
            followReq.map((frn, index) =>  (
                <Button 
                    key={frn}
                    title={`Follow ${frn}`}
                    onPress={() => doFollow(index)}
                />
            ))
        }
      </View> 
    );
  }
```

or bind navigation params to your app state and access like below if your app uses react-redux

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

render(){
      const followReq = this.props.followRequest;
      const doFollow = this.props.doFollow;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
            followReq.map((frn, index) =>  (
                <Button 
                    key={frn}
                    title={`Follow ${frn}`}
                    onPress={() => doFollow(index)}
                />
            ))
        }
      </View> 
    );
  }


const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    ...props.navigation.state.params
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```